# KVM Switch and Happy Hacking Keyboard Pro 2

Tags: keyboard

I have been using HHKB Pro 2 for almost a year, one at home and one at work. Now I have to work with two computers (PC and Mac) for which I decided to buy KVM switch.
I picked one and expected nothing wrong with that, but when I plugged it in, HHKB was not working either with PC nor with Mac. I tried several keyboards and all worked flawlessly expect the mentioned HHKB. I tried the second one with the same result. With that in mind, I purchased another KVM switch, which was hardware switched (the previous one listened to ScrollLock which is supported by HHKB by using Fn key). To my surprise, it didn't work either. 
Now I have tho KVM switches that work flawlessly with any keyboard BUT that damned HHKB Pro 2.
Is there any KVM switch that can handle this (or to be more precise, is there any that HHKB can deal with, because obviously there's something wrong with HHKB, not with KVMs).

Do you have any experience with that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HHKB Pro 2 has got USB hub and that seems to be causing trouble with most of the KVM switches.

KVM switches expect keyboard to be attached to its keyboard port.  So when HHKB Pro 2 is attached, KVM switch finds an USB hub and just stops.  It won't go beyond USB hub to look for keyboard which might be attached to it.

So are there any KVM switches that works fine with HHKB Pro 2?
One of the ATEN's KVM switch worked although it was a bit unstable.
May be their recent models might work with increased stability if you want to give it a try.

However, I would suggest free software solution like "Synergy" (http://synergy-foss.org/) if you have display for each of your computers.

Comment: Thanks, I am using Synergy right now, but wanted HW solution, but now I see it's futile with this keyboard. Kind of disappointing, but thanks for your answer, it helped me really much. Thanks again.